# Linq Query to find the max resemblence between two objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I got this data-base scheme:[image]

I am trying to write a Linq query that will return the Users with similar(Identical by ID) tastes in movies for a given User-name. basically I need to find another User that has watched as much similar movies as my given user-"Input User"(if there are more than one users that watch the maximum amount then I need to take the first user from the list), then I need to recommend to my input user for films that that the found user had watched and he didn't in a decending order according to the rank that the "found" user had ranked those films.

I am quite lost.. by now I got a result set for the movies(and their rank from the UserMovieRank table of the "Input user") and have no idea how to proceed.

My database is within SQL-SERVER 2008 R2 if it matters to anyone..

Thank you.

Comment: movies similar are movies with the same ID.. so if user "A" watched the movies: 1111,2222,3333,4444 and user "B" watched movies:2222,3333 but user "C" watched: 2222,3333,4444,5555,6666 then user "C" will be picked and user user "A" will get a recommendation to watch movie 5555 and 6666 (order of them shown would be subject to how user C ranked them - from high to low (rank is from 1-10))since he didn't watch them yet.

Comment: There are a number of different algorithms for for comparing objects for best fit.  I would recommend searching web for the algorithm you want to use before writing any code.  Right now your are designing your software and not ready to start coding.

Comment: Lets say the most similar user has an identical watch list... wouldn't it then be better to pick someone else who can actually be used to recommend new movies? ;)

Answer (score 0):

this will find the best match. its not 100% of what you want but is should help you start

```
 var currentUserMovies=UserMovieRanks.Where(u=>u.userId==userId).Select(m=>m.movieId).ToList();

    var userMovieMatch = TwitterUsers.Where(u => u.userID != userId).Select(tu=>
    {
        var userMovies=UserMovieRanks.Where(u=>u.userId==tu.userID).Select(m=>m.movieId).ToList();
        return new   {
            MovieIds=userMovies,
            Count=userMovies.Count(c=>currentUserMovies.Contains(c)),
            NotWatchedByUser=userMovies.Except(currentUserMovies)
        };
    });

    var bestPick=userMovieMatch.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Count).First();
```